# Transparent header on scroll to full colour - Nav overlay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onscroll

Currently my site has a transparent navbar when on scroll will change to full colour. The issue i am having is that the navbar also switches colour when the page is scrolled on the fullscreen navigation.

How can i stop the navbar switching colour when the fullscreen navigation is open? Would i need to change me JS?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-btn a").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
  });

  $('.overlay').on('click', function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
    $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
  });

  $('.menu a').on('click', function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
    $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 100) {
      $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#dedede");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.menu-btn {
  z-index: 999;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.menu-btn a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* safari hack */
}

.btn-open:after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f394";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-open:hover:after {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-close:after {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f2d7";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear 0s;
  transition-property: all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-close:hover:after {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* OVERLAY */

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(209, 180, 0, 0.96);
}

.overlay .menu {
  margin: 15% auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.overlay .menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay .menu ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 0 0 0;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.overlay .menu ul li#social {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.overlay .menu ul li a {
  color: #d1b400;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
}

.overlay .menu ul li#social a {}

.overlay .menu ul ul {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.overlay .menu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.overlay .menu ul ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.overlay .menu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}


/* RESPONSIVE */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .overlay .menu ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .overlay .menu ul li:last-child {
    border: 0;
  }
  .overlay .menu ul ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .menu-btn {
    right: 25px;
  }
}

.allexamples {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #333;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu-social {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .4em;
}

.menu-social a {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("../img/cd-socials.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* image replacement */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-social .menu-facebook a {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.menu-social .menu-instagram a {
  background-position: -44px 0;
}

.menu-social .menu-dribbble a {
  background-position: -88px 0;
}

.menu-social .menu-twitter a {
  background-position: -132px 0;
}

.overlay .menu ul ul li.description {
  padding: 0px 0 10px 0px;
}

.overlay .menu ul ul li.description span {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: none;
}

p.tel,
p.email {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
}

p.tel a {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  font-size: 20px!important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p.email a {
  color: #fff!important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  font-size: 20px!important;
  text-transform: none;
}

.menu-btn a span {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/pb-white.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
      </a>
      <span class="navbar-text">
        <div class="menu-btn">
          <a class="btn-open" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span>MENU</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Brand Development, Logos, Point, Point</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Website Design, Website Development, Point, Point</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Business Cards, Leaflets, Point, Point</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Packaging</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Point, Point, Point, Point</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Infographics</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Point, Point, Point, Point</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>About Company</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Examples & Case Studies of our work</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="description"><span>Get in touch with us to get your project started</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="social">
          <ul class="contact">
            <p class="email"><a href="mailto:info@company.com">info@company.com</a></p>
            <p class="tel"><a href="tel:01231212312">01234 566545</a></p>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:2000px;"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/whitinggg/pen/bLzxGG

Comment: did you try checking if `.overlay` is visible or hidden before setting color on `.navbar`? `if($(".overlay").is(":hidden")) { 
          $(".navbar").css("background-color" , "#dedede");
        } else {
          $(".navbar").css("background-color" , "transparent");
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can stop the navbar switching color when the fullscreen navigation by small editing in your script like this**

**change your script like this**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu-btn a").click(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');

        if( $(this).hasClass('btn-close') ) { 
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
        } 
        else if( scroll > 100) {
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#dedede");
        }
    });

    $('.overlay').on('click', function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });

    $('.menu a').on('click', function () {
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
        $(".menu-btn a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 100) {
            if($('.overlay:visible').length == 0) {
                $(".navbar").css("background-color", "#dedede");
            }
        } else {
            $(".navbar").css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works well. Except if you scroll the page and then click the menu button, the colour still comes through?

Comment: When navigation fullscreen state ?? or default ??

Comment: So default, when the page loads scroll until nav changes color. Then click menu and color still comes through?

Comment: In default state you can't click the menu when you scroll down . Because menu scroll when you scroll down .
Your menu not fixed.

Comment: So you are not seeing this then? [link] https://ibb.co/np4qOH @anzilkhan

Comment: @Chris i change mine answer , please check .
If this is ok , then let me know ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166048/discussion-between-anzil-khan-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

You may consider adding an `!important` to the background style in order to always keep it transparent:

```
.navbar.fixed-top {
   background:transparent!important;
}
```